# How to persist privateConversation data while using botframework's luisaction binding?

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I have followed [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/blog-LUISActionBinding#what-is-luis-action-binding) and used it in my bot. One thing I could not figure out is how do I persist the users data.

for example:

```
 user: what is my status?
 bot: could you provide your id?
 user: its xxx
 bot: its in so and so stage.
```

now if user ask same question bot is not supposed to ask for id (should answer directly)

```
 user: what is my current status?
 bot: what is your id?       <--------- this is not expected of the bot.
```